# Conditionally Changing image of button in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

How to change a image of the button in oracle apex conditionally ?

Imagine there are two images as `A.png` and `B.png`. I have a sql query and if that query returns at least one row, image of the button should be `A.png`. else image of the button should be `B.png`.

How could i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a hidden field in the HTML and have it populated with the number of rows the SQL query returned like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE;`

Use `APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN()` to create hidden field, the hidden item name (`id` for HTML) could be "abcID".
Hidden field HTML (somewhere in the `<body>` of the HTML) will be like-

```
<input type=hidden id="abcId" name="abcName"/>
```

Then, you can add this javascript to change the button image. You will have to include a `onload` event in the HTML `<body>` to call a function.

```
<html>
<body onload=changeImage()>
....
....
<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage()
    {
      if (document.getElementById("abcId").value) > 0){
          document.getElementById("ButtonID").src ="/path/to/A.png";
      else{
          document.getElementById("ButtonID").src ="/path/to/B.png";
      }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```